# Typescript: How to assign enum to object property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im writing TS interfaces/types to existing js library, which is exported as two module types (IIFE and ES6).

It has enum eg:

```
export declare enum ExampleEnum {
    HELLO = "HELLO"
}
```

But at IIFE version it has global object where enum is assigned, so user can use it as in example below:

```
window.test.ExampleEnum.HELLO
```

Any idea how to tell Typescript that ExampleEnum is whole enum object, not a value of it?

```
declare global {
  var test: { ExampleEnum: ? }
}
```

Comment: *"But at IIFE version it has global object where enum is assigned..."* Please *show us* that assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
declare global {
  var test: { ExampleEnum: ? }
}
```

to this:

```
declare global {
  var test: {
    ExampleEnum: typeof ExampleEnum;
  }
}
```

This should allow you to use **window.test.ExampleEnum** as the whole enum object.